# How to join to the Facebook group using Graph Api?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to join to the Facebook group from the iOS application but i could not find any document about how to join Facebook group. How can i find the solution ?

Answer (score 3):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/group/members

I believe you cannot invite or join with the API. Well, you can invite under specific circumstances, only in "App groups", which is most likely not what you want.